# where is make_request_fn source code in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

in my study and examine linux kernel code I encountered with function *make_request_fn*. in [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=make_request_fn) link it says that this function type definition is in *include/linux/blkdev.h, line 211* :

```
typedef void (make_request_fn) (struct request_queue *q, struct bio *bio);
```

but did not mention where is its implementation as source code in a .c file.
my question is where is this function source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef void (make_request_fn) (struct request_queue *q, struct bio *bio);
```

This is not a **function declaration**. It is definition of **function type**. Later in the same file [include/linux/blkdev.h, line 299](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/blkdev.h#L299), the same name gets the field in `request_queue` structure.

And [in file drivers/md/bcache/request.c on line 1140](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/md/bcache/request.c#L1140), there is assigned function `flash_dev_make_request` to this field, which makes you think that you call function `make_request_fn()`, but you really call `flash_dev_make_request()`.

It is really basic way of providing Encapsulation and Polymorphism and really basic OOP model in C.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like different kernel versions have different function layout. I am working on Linux Kernel 4.9. make_request_fn is initialized by blk_queue_make_request() function in blk-core.c.